# Sys Routing Table Router: Destination IP, Gateway IP and Public IP are different, something unusual?

Tags: routing, router, ip, ip-forwarding-table

I am currently studying my home network router Sys Routing Table and attempting to resolve WHY my Public IP (assigned by my ISP), Gateway IP (WAN) and Destination Network (WAN) are all different.

I assume the Gateway IP would be identical to my Public IP as I believe the Destination Network IP is an internal network at my ISP.

For example, this is what I am seeing:
Destination Network (WAN): 205.211.222.192 
Gateway IP (WAN): 205.211.222.254 
Public IP: 205.211.222.208

It appears the ISP has a different Gateway IP assigned to my router as the Public IP is obviously not a match.

From what I can tell, the Destination Network is an internal network at the ISP.

The Gateway IP is a secondary IP, assigned to my router. Public IP is another IP, assigned to my router?

The latter two points is where I am confused.

I did some pretty intense research on this and getting mixed results and answers as to why this is happening.

I am not running any independent Firewalls or otherwise. Just a standard TP-Link Archer C9 with default settings.

This was another article I read on this exchange, but seemed to be a variant issue (different setup):

[Why is my Router's WAN IP different from public IP?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20063/why-is-my-routers-wan-ip-different-from-public-ip)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: Hi Ron, I a apologize for posting incorrectly. I will check out that other forum in relation to this topic. Should I delete it from here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your router's WAN side is part of a subnet. From its own public IP it has to use the default gateway (upstream router) for destination addresses outside that subnet. This gateway needs to be located within the subnet. This is perfectly normal.

If you need to understand subnets, prefixes and such check out [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers).